# How can I get the ID and title of a post in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I get the ID and title of a post in PHP?  Each post has an ID and a title, and I need to be able to get both.

```
ID#      Title
1013     Name
1025     Name
```

Comment: Are you using a database to store the data or a file? If you are using MySQL, there are plenty of tutorials out there available for `fetch data mysql with php` that will assist you in this task. Here is a link to the first result I found: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/retrieve-data-from-a-mysql-database.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear. Assuming you use MySQL, you can get the id and the title of a post like this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT id, title FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result)
{
    echo 'The query failed.<br />';
    echo mysql_error();
}
else
{
    //check if there are results
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo 'No results.';
    }
    else
    {
        //loop through the results
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo 'ID: ' . $row['id'] . ', name: ' . $row['title'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you -- That works! Appreciate the time. My PHP is really weak. -- Mike